# how to override Comparer

Tags: c#, datetime, comparison

```
bool same = System.Collections.Comparer.Default.Compare(one,two) == 0;
```

I have a line like above in my project. Now when the Compare function is supplied with DateTime objects( ie if 'one' and 'two' are datetimes) I need to do a custom logic in comparison operation. For all other data types default comparison is good. I am not sure how to override it. I know that there is comparer but not sure how to achieve without modifying above line. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "custom logic" you intend to implement?

Comment: I need to convert both datetime objects to utc and compare.  I don’t have any control over the incoming date times. One may be local and the other may be utc. So the safest way to check for equality is to convert both to utc iin the custom logic and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`. They already compare using their equivalent UTC times.